# Program skips cin.getline()

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character-arrays

I have made this program, It get the users adress, name and work. Then It puts it all into one string and outputs that string. (I know there are better ways to do this)

```
char str[600];
char adrs[200];
char name[10];
char wrk[200];
cout<<"Enter your name and press ENTER: ";
cin.getline(name,10);
cout<<"\nEnter your adress and press ENTER:";
cin.getline(adrs,200);
cout<<"\nEnter your workplace and press ENTER:";
cin.getline(wrk,200);
strcpy(str,"My name is ");
strcat(str,name);
strcat(str,"\nand i live at ");
strcat(str,adrs);
strcat(str, "\nI also work at ");
strcat(str, wrk); strcat(str, "\n\n");
cout<<str<<endl;
```

Here when I write a name that exceeds 10 chars The program does take the first 9 chars the user entered as I expected but after that It skips all the next `cin.getline()` That are in the program and goes to output `str` and ends the program.

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible you have a typo, such as `10` where you meant to have `100`?

Comment: Don't use member-`getline`. Use the free `std::getline` and `std::string`.

Comment: There was a typo in the code it was supposed to be 10 not 100

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil, so what, there's no adresses or names longer than 200/100 symbols?

Comment: I just used 10 to be easy to test. It would be a pain to try to write 1000 chars just to test

Comment: std::getline(std::cin, input)

Answer (score 8):

Every time you use cin, it stores every character entered in memory until it encounters a newline character. This block of memory is called the input buffer. Your first call to `cin.getline()` requests a string with 10 characters, including the terminating NULL character. However, cin happily reads as many characters as the user types until he hits the Enter key. If the user types more than 9 characters, then `cin` stores the remaining characters in the input buffer and will use them during later input operations. For example, if the user types 15 characters, your call to `cin.getline()` store the first nine in your c-string array. Calling `cin.getline()` again will then continue reading the remainder of the input that was already entered.

To fix this problem, you should use [`cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip past this newline character. I strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with online references to the C++ libraries. Two of my favorites are http://www.cplusplus.com and http://www.cppreference.com.

**Edit:** In order for my answer to be complete, I also need to add that `cin.getline()` will set the fail bit if there are more characters in the input buffer than requested. Before using `cin` for any additional input operations, you must call `cin.clear()` to clear the fail bit.

Comment: -1, `std::cin.flush` doesn't exist. At least in the 2003 C++ standard, §27.6.1.1 doesn't list `flush` as a member of `basic_istream`.

Comment: @Robᵩ My apologies. It should be `cin.ignore()`. I have fixed my answer along with a link to www.cppreference.com.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil I have added some details to help explain how an input buffer works.

Comment: Since cin.getline always leaves a newline in the memory. Why is it when I insert less than 10 chars the program works.

Comment: This is false. From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/ "If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it."

Comment: After further investigation, I see that my statement is incorrect. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Lets try it. Nope adding cin.ignore() after cin.getline doesnt work.

Comment: I still have the same problem.   And also Cin.getline doesnt keep reading the rest of the input in the other cin.getline()  It just skips them and at the end the program is printing nothing except the name.

Comment: @Code-Guru I really need your help

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil, check my answer. Your problem has *nothing* to do with a stuck character.

Comment: Did you look at the reference page that I gave a link to (in particular, the link directly to the `cin.ignore()` reference)? There is a very good example of how to use `cin.ignore()` correctly.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for jumping in here. I just found the correct solution myself after looking more closely at the references that I linked.

Comment: Im a real beginner so looking at references isn't gonna help me since i don't even understand what they are saying

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil Which is exactly why you need to start reading them. The more often you do it the more they will make sense.

Comment: @MarkRansom I cant find your answer :(

Answer (score 3):

When a too-long string is read, `ios_base::failbit` is set for the stream and all subsequent operations against the stream will fail. You need to reset the failure with [`ios::clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/clear/):

```
if (cin.fail())
    cin.clear();
```

After the error is cleared you may want to ignore the rest of the line with [`istream::ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/).

**Edit:** It took a helpful hint for me to figure out how to use `ignore` properly. Here's the total solution.

```
cout<<"Enter your name and press ENTER: ";
cin.getline(name,10);
if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

I would suggest putting all that code into a function so that you can call it after every `getline`.

Comment: `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');` will work similar to your hand-crafted loop. However, you are correct that the **real** solution is to clear the fail bit.

Comment: @Code-Guru, thanks! I didn't see the second parameter for some reason - I'll make the change now.

Comment: Both parameters have default values. The second defaults to EOF which isn't very useful with `std::cin` IMO.

Comment: Oh, and my version of the first argument probably compiles, but isn't technically correct since its type is really a typedef. I didn't take the time to look up the exact one that should be used.

Answer (score 2):

`cin.getline(name,10);` reads at most NINE characters from the input, stopping earlier if there's a newline.  If there's no newline in those 9 characters, it won't touch the rest of the line, and the next call to `getline` will continue reading the rest of the line.

If you want to just ignore the rest of the input line, you could instead use:

```
cin.get(name, 10);
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

The free function `std::getline` operates on `std::string`s, which are much easier to deal with than character arrays. Particularly, `std::getline` allows for arbitrarily-large input lines.

Try this:

```
std::string str;
std::string adrs;
std::string name;
std::string wrk;
cout<<"Enter your name and press ENTER: ";
std::getline(std::cin, name);
cout<<"\nEnter your adress and press ENTER:";
std::getline(std::cin, adrs);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is sound, the issue is that when you declare a char array of size 10, you don't actually get 10 spots to put characters in, you only get nine. The last one is reserved to signify the end of the string. [Here ][1] is a reference is you would like to read up more on the issue:

Just declare one character more than the number you want. There are many excellent tips on how to flush the stream, ignore the rest of the line, etc that you can use as well.

Good luck!