# Reading input into a C-style string

Tags: c++, c, string

I am working on a project for my programming class that requires me to work with strings. The program begins by asking the user to input a phrase. Normally I would declare something such as:

```
    string phrase;
```

Then I would use:

```
    getline(cin,phrase);
```

However, the professor told the class that we aren't allowed to use the string class, we must use only c-based strings. I could be wrong but I believe that c-based strings look something like this:

```
    char phrase[12] = "hello world";
```

If this is what my professor means by c-based strings, then I do not know how to input a phrase into them. When I attempt this, the program only stores the first word of the phrase and stops at the first space it sees. For example:

```
    char phrase[12];

    cin >> phrase;

//input: hello world

    cout << phrase;

//output: hello
```

Any advice would help and would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `cin >> phrase;` and `cout << phrase;`?

Comment: Extraction is white-space delimited.

Comment: `However, the professor told the class that we aren't allowed to use the string class, we must use only c-based strings.`  This is why more and more students are going to Java and other languages and going away from C++.  Stupid rules like this...

Comment: Note that "hello world" is 12 characters, not 11.  Don't forget the terminating null character.

Comment: thank you I was typing too fast and wasn't being careful. And also I thought that [11] held 12 positions since it started with 0?

Comment: Your professor is giving very dangerous advise to your class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'd say it depends on *when* in the course it happens. At a certain level, a C++ developer should be capable of working with C-style strings.

Comment: @Angew Yeah, I'm only in programming 2. The professor doesn't frown upon string class he just wants us to be able to be able to do it this way as well.

Comment: `phrase[11]` holds 11 positions, indexed starting at 0 and ending at 10.

Comment: Okay @Code-Apprentice , you're right, I'm still learning haha.

Comment: Rather than use `char phrase[12] = "hello world";`, better to use `char phrase[] = "hello world";` and let the compiler right size the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `cin.getline(var_id, var_length)` and not `cin >> var_id`, which actually stops storing the input in the variable when it encounters a `space` or a `new line`.

If you want to know more about `cin.getline` and what problems its use can cause, you can have a look to this post: [Program skips cin.getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835226/program-skips-cin-getline)

Comment: Okay thank you, but how do I come up with the "var_length" if I don't know what the user will type in as the phrase?

Comment: Specify the buffer/array length. Create an array large enough, in your opinion.

Comment: @BCRwar1 `var_length` is the amount of input that you can accept. The user is allowed to type less than this. This is one of the limitations of using a fixed-sized array rather than the `string` class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have one last question. The next part of the program is a for loop that runs through the phrase one position at a time and stops when it gets to the end of the phrase. Example:     for(int k = 0; k < length ; k++ ) { phrase[k]; } I guess my question is, how do I determine length?

Comment: It ends when *i >= length*. If you want that the loop ends when the inputted phrase is finished, you could use this loop codition: *phrase[k] != '\0'*, because, remember, any c-string, to be such, has to terminate with a null-terminated character.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading input into a **static char array** you can use sizeof(charArray) to determine its maximum lengh. But take into consideration that the last symbol will be end of line, so you can read maximum **length-1** symbols into this array.

```
char phrase[12] ;
cin.getline(phrase, sizeof(phrase));
```